# net use fails with system error 67 with FQDN

Tags: windows-7, network-share, server-message-block, fqdn, net-use

I search for help with a confusing error with Windows 7 mounting a 
network fileshare.

The problem is that on machine A a mount with the FQDN fails (net use 
system error 67) while the same command with the IP address succeeds. On 
another machine B the mount is successful with both the FQDN and the IP. 
So I think it's not (only) a problem of the fileserver but of the local Windows system. Sadly I can't find any major configuration differences like 
Windows firewall restrictions or anything else.

### Machine A - FQDN (fails)

```
C:\Users\student>net use
Neue Verbindungen werden gespeichert.
Es sind keine Einträge in der Liste.

C:\Users\student>net use X: \\fs1-2-home.xxx.xxx.de\home\users\testuser
Systemfehler 67 aufgetreten.
Der Netzwerkname wurde nicht gefunden.

C:\Users\student>net use
Neue Verbindungen werden gespeichert.
Es sind keine Einträge in der Liste.
```

### Machine A - IP (succeeds)

```
C:\Users\student>net use
Neue Verbindungen werden gespeichert.
Es sind keine Einträge in der Liste.

C:\Users\student>net use X: \\xxx.xxx.xxx.67\home\users\testuser
Geben Sie den Benutzernamen für "xxx.xxx.xxx.67" ein: testuser
Geben Sie das Kennwort für "xxx.xxx.xxx.67" ein:
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.

C:\Users\student>net use
Neue Verbindungen werden gespeichert.
Status       Lokal     Remote                    Netzwerk
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           X:        \\xxx.xxx.xxx.67\home\users\testuser
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

I pinged the FQDN to be sure that it's not a DNS problem.

```
C:\Users\student>ping fs1-2-home.xxx.xxx.de
Ping wird ausgeführt für fs1-2-home.xxx.xxx.de [xxx.xxx.xxx.67] mit 32 Bytes Daten:

Antwort von xxx.xxx.xxx.67: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=62
Antwort von xxx.xxx.xxx.67: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=62
Antwort von xxx.xxx.xxx.67: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=62
Antwort von xxx.xxx.xxx.67: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=62

Ping-Statistik für xxx.xxx.xxx.67:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Mittelwert = 0ms

C:\Users\student>nslookup fs1-2-home.xxx.xxx.de
Server:  dns1.xxx.de
Address:  xxx.xxx.xxx.4

Name:    fs1-2-home.xxx.xxx.de
Address:  xxx.xxx.xxx.67
```

I also looked at Wireshark while executing the commands (with the FQDN) on both machines and it seemed 
that machine A is doing some parts differently than machine B. I noticed for
example that the NBSS session request differ in the called name.

### Machine A (fails)

```
NBSS    Session request, to FS1-2-HOME<20> from WINDOWS7_X64<00>
NBSS    Negative session response, Called name not present
NBSS    Session request, to FS1-2-HOME<20> from WINDOWS7_X64<00>
NBSS    Negative session response, Called name not present
```

### Machine B (succeeds)

```
NBSS    Session request, to *SMBSERV<00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00> from WINDOWS7_X64<00>
NBSS    Negative session response, Called name not present
NBSS    Session request, to *SMBSERVER<20> from WINDOWS7_X64<00>
NBSS    Positive session response
```

Has anyone come across a similiar problem and has some help for me? 
Thanks in advance:) .

Comment: your question is a solution to me: I use IP and could connect to my netdrive now!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to start Workstation service:

```
> net use X: \\Host\Share
System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found.

> net start lanmanworkstation

> net use X: \\Host\Share
The command completed successfully.
```